# How to convert coordinates between different coordinate systems with JMapProjLib, Proj4j or Proj4js?

Tags: java, javascript, coordinate-systems, wgs84, proj4js

I'm creating an Android app (with Java) which is going to read *SWEREF99 TM* coordinates from a file, and convert them to *WGS84* (long-lat) coordinates, and in the oposite direction. To do this, I'm going to use either *JMapProjLib*, *Proj4j* or *Proj4js* (JavaScript library which I'm going to access using Java's `ScriptEngine`).

The problem is that I can't figure out how to use the libraries, due to verry little documentation...
I've tried the *[JMapProjLib](https://github.com/OSUCartography/JMapProjLib)*-JavaLibrary, but it is not giving me the correct result, and I've also tried using *[Proj4js 2.3.3](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/releases)*, but I can't even get the later mentioned working...

JavaScript (and a bit of HTML) code that I'm currently using, with *[Proj4js 2.3.3](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/releases)* (currently I only try this script in an HTML file, so the browser should show a pop-up message saying "Done!" when the conversion is done):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Proj4js Testing</title>
</head>
<body onload="convertCoordinates()">
    <script type"text/javascript" src="proj4js.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Convert coordinates
        function convertCoordinates() 
            // Define the target projection (SWEREF99 TM)
            var targetProjection = "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";

            // Convert the WGS84 coordinates Lon: 15 and Lat: 55 to SWEREF99 TM coordinates
            proj4(targetProjection, [15, 55]);

            // Just show an alert message telling that the code has executed properly
            alert("Done!");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Java code that I'm trying (with *[JMapProjLib](https://github.com/OSUCartography/JMapProjLib)*):

```
/**
 * Convert a long-lat coordinate to a SWEREF99 TM coordinate.
 * 
 * @param longLatCoordinate The long-lat coordinate to convert.
 * 
 * @return The converted SWEREF99 TM coordinate.
 */
public static SWEREF99TMCoordinate longLatToSWEREF99TM(LongLatCoordinate longLatCoordinate) {
    // Create a new SWEREF99 TM projection
    Projection projection = ProjectionFactory.fromPROJ4Specification(new String[] {
            "+proj=tmerc",
            "+zone=33",
            "+ellps=GRS80",
            "+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
            "+units=m",
            "+no_defs"
    });

    // Convert the LongLatCoordinate to a Point2D.Double
    Point2D.Double longLatPoint = new Point2D.Double(longLatCoordinate.getLongitude(), longLatCoordinate.getLatitude());
    // Get the location as a SWEREF99 TM Point2D.Double
    Point2D.Double sweref99TMPoint = projection.transform(longLatPoint, new Point2D.Double());
    // COnvert the location to a SWEREF99TMCoordinate
    SWEREF99TMCoordinate sweref99TMCoordinate = new SWEREF99TMCoordinate(sweref99TMPoint.x, sweref99TMPoint.y);

    // Return the projected coordinate
    return sweref99TMCoordinate;
}
```

The *JMapProjLib*-library which is referenced to my Java project consists of the contents in the folder `src/com/jhlabs/map` and `src/coordsys/` in the git-repository compiled to a `.jar` file using *Eclipse*, by me.

As the *JavaScript*-library *[Proj4js](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/releases)* looks more "well-done" to me, I would prefer using it combined with the Java `ScriptEngine`, so what I really need now is just some kind of documentation, or someone who can explain this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this repository and extract what you need:

https://github.com/dsegerss/Sonardrone/tree/master/src/org/sonardrone/proj/positions